# Cannot get the index of a parent element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
<ul class="urls">
    <li class="url">0
        <ul class="url_qry_str">
            <ul>1</ul>
            <ul>2</ul>
            <ul>3</ul>
        </ul>
        <ul class="url_qry">
            <li>
                <button onclick="url_qry_add(event);">Add</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="url">1
        <ul class="url_qry_str">
            <ul>1</ul>
        </ul>
        <ul class="url_qry">
            <li>
                <button onclick="url_qry_add(event);">Add</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="url">2
        <ul class="url_qry_str">
            <ul>1</ul>
            <ul>2</ul>
        </ul>
        <ul class="url_qry">
            <li>
                <button onclick="url_qry_add(event);">Add</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```javascript
function url_qry_add(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).closest(".url").index());
});
```

I've been struggling with getting the index of the `li.url` position. What am I doing wrong?
http://jsfiddle.net/defaye/4a52gsj4/

Comment: I see nothing with the class `.qry_add`.

Comment: In your fiddle, change the menu from `OnLoad` to `No Wrap" so the `url_qry_add` function will be in the global scope.

Comment: To all those who have downvoted can you undo that, I've just updated the question and removed all my typos. And @quint I don't know what you're referring to.

Comment: You don't? You just a moment ago removed the code I was referring to: `$(".qry_add").click(function (e) {`. Now you've radically changed your question, so it no longer has the same meaning. This is a common issue. The value of `this` does not refer to the element bound when you use handler attributes.

Comment: I know. I had not meant for that code to get incorporated into the question hence I cocked up with various typos all over the place setting up the test. I cleaned it all up now though but the damage has been done and the readers have come and downvoted to their heart's content already. Cheers guys!

Comment: You don't want to get down voted, take more care in posting your question.

Comment: `<button onclick="url_qry_add(this, event);">Add</button>` ... `function url_qry_add(elem, e) {` ... `$(elem).closest...`

Comment: I always take care over my questions but sometimes a slip up happens. I'm sure you can understand that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64551/discussion-between-squint-and-defaye).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This jsfiddle example works. I think it was failing because `this` was actually the Window class, not the button element.

http://jsfiddle.net/wy9g8cdp/

```js
function url_qry_add(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(e.target).closest(".url").index());
};
```

```html
<ul class="urls">
    <li class="url">0
        <ul class="url_qry_str">
            <ul>1</ul>
            <ul>2</ul>
            <ul>3</ul>
        </ul>
        <ul class="url_qry">
            <li>
                <button onclick="url_qry_add(event);">Add</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="url">1
        <ul class="url_qry_str">
            <ul>1</ul>
        </ul>
        <ul class="url_qry">
            <li>
                <button onclick="url_qry_add(event);">Add</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="url">2
        <ul class="url_qry_str">
            <ul>1</ul>
            <ul>2</ul>
        </ul>
        <ul class="url_qry">
            <li>
                <button onclick="url_qry_add(event);">Add</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I do apologise. I had not meant to run my question example code to be using the `.on` version of the function. I'm trying to make it work with a named function.

Comment: alternatively with your old method you can use $(e.target) to get the source button

Comment: this is really elegant. @squint suggests passing `onclick(this, event);` but your solution is bypassing this?

Comment: I think it is supported in all browsers and ie9+. if you need earlier support you might need this: `$(e.target || e.srcElement)`